# TPM Attestation - sequence diagram?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

i was looking at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-tpm-attestation#validate-the-nonce-and-receive-credentials

The last step is not much clear:  “With the Nonce challenge completed, the service allows the device to provision.”

Well…  once the device pass the nonce challenge what’s happening?   Does the DPS will provide back to the device the IoT Hub connection string with a standard Shared Access Key? 
Does this shared key is stored in the TPM?

On the next restart of IoT Edge does the DPS flow start again from scratch?   Or the Edge Agent just rely on the Shared Access Key that was already retrieved from a previews attestation with DPS?

Thanks

Rgz

Alberto Gorni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the nonce challenge is passed, DPS continues the provisioning flow by determining which IoT hub to register the device to, registering the device in that IoT hub, and then returning the IoT hub hostname to the device (same steps as happen after an X.509 device establishes its identity).

For your second question, IIRC IoT Edge goes through the provisioning flow on restart.

Comment: Thanks Nicole, an additional details: once DPS provide the IoT Hub hostname then for the authentication we just rely on the IAuthenticationMethod, so DPS doesn't enter into the matter of how device then will authenticate to IoT Hub, right?